# shared file synchronization (read/write)

Tags: php, c, linux, synchronization, read-write

I wrote in PHP code that it will "fopen" a file(lets call it TXT) and write there the chosen checkbox, then later another process(lets call it PROC1- in c code) needs to read the file(TXT).

I need to  synchronized it, I mean to block the process(PROC1) from reading, while the PHP writes into the shared resource (TXT).

does fopen take care of it?  I think that the diffident between it and the open() method..

or maybe to use pipe(), but as I've seen it runs only commands and not opening a file..

Thanks again in advance..

Comment: For how long will the first file lock the txt file? A couple of microseconds or an hour or two?

Comment: If it's the IPC tool - then you should use pipes.

Comment: how to use pipe(), but as I've seen it runs only commands and not opening a file..

Comment: If you want to pipe data from one process to another, look into [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Answer (score 1):

No, fopen does not take care of this. You can use [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) to synchronize access to the file.

Note that all processes will have to flock() the file before using it, it depends on the platform, but flock() is usually advisory locks, meaning anyone can just bypass the lock if they so wish (e.g. if they forget to call flock())